# I am setting a value in the HTML for my radio buttons. Using Javascript, how can I get that value?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Using Javascript, I need to get the `value` part of whichever radio button the user selects.

Here is my HTML:

```
<div>
    <label>
        <input type="radio" name="seasonType" value="spring" checked="checked" />
        Spring
    </label>
</div>
<div>
    <label>
        <input type="radio" name="seasonType" value="summer" />
        Summer
    </label>
</div>
```

So I am trying it like this:

```
let seasonType = document.querySelector('input[name="seasonType"]:checked');
const seasonTypeVal = seasonType.checked;
console.log(" writing out seasonTypeVal => ", seasonTypeVal);
```

But the results are just either `true` or `false` like this in console:

```
 writing out seasonTypeVal => true
```

How can I get the actual value?

Thanks!

Comment: You need `.value` not `.checked`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Get the value with `value` attribute `seasonType.value`

You don't require `:checked` in the querySelector. Use

`let seasonType = document.querySelector('input[name="seasonType"]')`